# Contact and communication management software

Tags: communication, contact-manager, crm

I want something like CRM for sales (such as HubSpot).
But the problem with HubSpot is that it's very focused on selling.

What I don't want: marketing, sale tracking, email campaigns.

What I want it to organize and manage: all my contacts, their email, social media profile, LinkedIn profile info, photos, etc. as well as history of my communication with that contact, e.g. the emails that we exchanged, Skype call notes, phone calls, meeting minutes, leaving notes, etc.

This seems so obvious, I wonder why I cannot find tons of such software already?!

Any suggestion for software that does this: contact and communication history management?

Comment: "*history of my communication with that contact, e.g. the emails that we exchanged, Skype call notes, phone calls, meeting minutes, leaving notes, etc.*": Does this need to be recorded automatically? If yes, please precise what email/etc software you are using. If not, you would input everything manually?

Answer (score 1):

We have used Pipedrive for a long time. I think it has all you are looking for. But why don't you want to use Hubspot CRM? It is free and very similar to Pipedrive.

Both systems have email-Integration (Gmail, ..), you can have a history of your email communication, and take notes to any other communication. You can plan tasks and save notes to your contacts or deals at any time.

Comment: I like Hubspot, but it is limited, I cannot add body off emails, business card image, I cannot import previous email from GMAIL (since I cannot verify the forwarding email address), after all it is focused for selling and not actually contact management for managers and alike.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still searching, there is a [Contact and Communication Management Software](https://simitless.com/en/templates?or=st&preview=templates-contact-and-communication-hist) template on [Simitless](https://www.simitless.com/). What you can do with it is, for example:

- You can create your own CRM with just the focus you need (i.e. no marketing, sales tracking or email campaigns).
- You can track your contacts, their email, social media profiles, upload photos, and track and record your communication history with your contacts via a simple copy/paste and/or input your own notes into the specific field.
- Your app is always accessible online, it can be shared with whoever you want (or not shared, your choice), it is private and secure. You can trigger your email client from the app and launch Skype calls when you have the corresponding data. And, you can import and export data.

It sounds like it can suit your need, from the way I understood your problem. Check it out.

**Full disclosure: I am part of the startup that designed that platform.** We just launched recently, still in beta. If you want to try it out and need some help, I can definitely give you a hand. Here is a little screenshot what it looks like with some "dummy data" I input into the template:

[image]

And, since it is just a template, you can take it as a basis and modify it to your heart's desire.)

Comment: The question explicitly asks for "communication history management". Could you please detail how "the emails that we exchanged, Skype call notes, phone calls" get recorded, and how you can then search/browse them?

Comment: The communication history management would be done by the user inputting a note or a record into the specific field of the app. To my knowledge, there is as of yet no app that integrates with every email/chat/communication system existing so that it can be fully automatized. From what I know, the most universal and easiest system to do such a thing is a quick copy/paste into the specifically designed app. I'll update the answer to reflect that.